# jQuery hover problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I would like to slide an element out when the mouse goes over and then slide it back and hide when the mouse goes out..I have this code, but I have problem when the mouse leave the element before the first mouseenter function is completed..The `.entry_extend` div stay visible. I tried to the hover function, but is the same problem..Please help..Thanks.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
                    jQuery(".fire").mouseenter(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('.entry_extend').stop(true, false).show('slide',null,500,null);

                    });
                    jQuery(".fire").mouseleave(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('.entry_extend').stop(true, false).hide('slide',null,500,null);
                    });

                });


<div id="craft" class="fire">
       <div class="entry_main">
           <a href="" title="">
             <img src="" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="entry_ex_craft" class="entry_extend">
           <a href="" title="">original shisha pipe collection</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Please Help:)

Comment: Could you post the markup you are testing this on?

Comment: your html would be really helpful

Comment: good point..I will post it in while

Comment: so it's there right now..under the jQuery code..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement a "hover". This works:

```
jQuery(".fire").hover(
    function(){jQuery('.entry_extend', this).stop(true, true).show(500);}
    ,
    function(){jQuery('.entry_extend', this).stop(true, true).hide(500);}
);
```

Mind you, it isn't a good idea to have the DIV you are sliding in and out within the DIV you are hovering on, since HIDING the DIV alters the boundaries of the DIV containing it. You can end up with some "trembling" activity sometimes because of this.

Comment: Oh..Cool..Thanks..But can I ask why the '.entry_extend' does not select all of these elements on my page? I thought this selector means I am selecting more distinct elements..? Am I wrong? Sure I am:)

Comment: The second parameter to the selector ('.entry_extend', this), forces it to "look for elements with a class of "entry_entend" ONLY in the element pointed to by "this". i.e.  children of the "this" element. It is the same as using the "children('.entry_extend')" method, but is (in my opinion) easier to use. For example you would say "jQuery('div .tabs')" rather than "jQuery('div').children('.tabs')".

Answer (score 0):

try combining mouseover+mouseenter  and mouseout+mouseleave  using binding.. see [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm):

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
                    jQuery(".fire").bind('mouseover mousenter',function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('.entry_extend').stop(true, false).show('slide',null,500,null);

                    });
                    jQuery(".fire").bind('mouseout mouseleave',function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('.entry_extend').stop(true, false).hide('slide',null,500,null);
                    });

                });
```